# Comparing two Dataframes and creating a third one where certain contions are met

Tags: python, dataframe, compare, comparison, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to compare two different `dataframe` that have the same column names and indexes(not numerical) and  I need to obtain a third `df` with the biggest value for the row with the same column name.

**Example**

```
df1=

|  | col_1 | col2 | col-3 |

| rft_12312 | 4 | 7 | 4 |

| rft_321321 | 3 | 4 | 1 |
```

```
df2=

|  | col_1 | col2 | col-3 |

| rft_12312 | 7 | 3 | 4 |

| rft_321321 | 3 | 7 | 6 |
```

**Required result**

```
|  | col_1 | col2 | col-3 |

| rft_12312 | 7 (because df2.value in this \[row :column\] \>df1.value) | 7 | 4 |


| rft_321321 | 3(when they are equal doesn't matter from which column is the value) | 7 | 6 |
```

I've already tried pd.update with filter_func defined as:

def filtration_function(val1,val2):
if val1 >= val2:
return val1
else:
return val2

but is not working. I need the check for each column with same name.

also **pd.compare** but does not allow me to pick the right values.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hello. Please format the code correctly. We can't read it in this state ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one possibility would be to use "combine". This method generates an element-wise comparsion between the two dataframes and returns the maximum value of each element.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

def filtration_function(val1, val2):
    return max(val1, val2)

result = df1.combine(df2, filtration_function)
```

I think method "where" can work to:

```
import pandas as pd

result = df1.where(df1 >= df2, df2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was the where function. But do you know if the comparison is based on names of the columns(so the order matters or....)?

Comment: The comparison is based on the values in the dataframes and not the column names. The order of the columns does not matter in this case.